# How to get the video from document library and show or Display the video on HOME page using Rest API (Client side only)

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

How to get the video from document library and show or Display the video on HOME page using Rest API (Client-side only)

Comment: you can use a Media webpart

Answer (score 1):

use`https://jcrowleyapps.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents')/Files`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Videos')/Items(1)/FieldValuesAsHtml",
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
    success: function (data) {
        var result = ""; 
        var uploadvideo = data.d.VideoSetDefaultEncoding;
        var thumbnail = data.d.AlternateThumbnailUrl;
        var title = data.d.FileLeafRef;
        var myVid = $(uploadvideo).attr('href');
        var thumbnailURL=$(thumbnail).attr('href');

                    var html = '<div><div style="background-image:url(\'' + thumbnailURL + '\')"><a  href='+ myVid + ' target="_blank"></a></div></div>';

                    result = result + html;             
                    $(".videoplaceholder").html(result);    
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error : " + data);
    }
});
```

This way you will get the videos based on item id. If you want to provide play functionality, you can jwplayer.

Comment: I try this one but URL is not working "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Videos')/Items(1)/FieldValuesAsHtml"

Comment: here you need to replace Videos with your listname and Items(1) is the itemid.

Comment: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document')/Items(1) up to here it is working  remaining part (FieldValuesAs‌​Html) is not working

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below code snippet works for you. Just change the name of your list/document library, change Title of the video in filter and put this code in a content editor webpart.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=Title,File/ServerRelativeUrl&$filter=Title eq 'TestVideo'&$expand=File",
                method: "GET",
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
            success: function (data) {
                var html = ""; 
                var vidURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + data.d.results[0].File.ServerRelativeUrl;
                html = '<source src="'+ vidURL +'" type="video/mp4">';
                $("#vidPlayer").append(html);    
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("ErrorMessage : " + data);
            }
        });

    });
</script> 

<div id="MyVideo"> 
    <video width="320" height="240" id="vidPlayer" controls="visible"> 
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: 'TestVideo'&$expand=File (In place TestVideo i given my video name in place of file i given Library name) .

Comment: dont replace File. Replace "Documents" with your library name and "TestVideo" with your video name(value of Title field):


/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<YourLibrary Name>')/items?$select=Title,File/ServerRelativeUrl&$filter=Title eq '<Your Video Name>'&$expand=File"